# Changing limit and derivative operator

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

I was trying to solve the following problem:

Let $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function such that

$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=1$ and

$\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(x)=a$.

Then find the value of $a$.

My brother who is not a pure math student suggested that take derivative on first equation you will get $a=0$.
I am not sure whether we can do that or not. Can we do that? I don't think it's the correct way of solving this.

Comment: Of course you can't take the derivative on the first one, because the first one isn't even an equality of functions. You can differentiate functions, but not numbers. Having said that, $a=0$ is a correct guess, in light of the constant function $1$.

Comment: Easy option is via mean value theorem. But you may apply the all too famous L'Hospital's Rule on $f(x) /x$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh  How can we use L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: Apply it on $f(x) /x $ (it is of the form "$\text {anything} /\infty $") and you get $f'(x) $. It follows $f(x) /x\to a$. But you know that $f(x) /x\to 0$ so we are done!!

Comment: I will however recommend the easy option of mean value theorem. Try applying MVT on $f(x+1)-f(x)$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I never knew this form of L'Hopital rule exists. Can you provide some references where I can find more about it?

Comment: You can see the proof (and not the statement) of L'Hospital's Rule in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't take the derivative in a limit. But the way a continuously differentiable map can have a limit while the derivative doesn't. Example: $f(x) = 1+ \frac{\sin x^2}{x}$ (defined for $x>0$).

However, you can solve the problem in following way.

Suppose that $a >0$, then for $x$ large enough, say $x\ge M >0$ you have $f^\prime(x) \ge a/2$. And applying Mean Value Theorem, $f(x) \ge a/2(x-M) + f(M)$ for $x \ge M$. Which implies that $ \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} = \infty$. In contradiction with $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)=1$ .

You can proceed in a similar way for $a<0$.

Hence the only option is $a=0$.